# Rope modelling issue - curve modifier breaks up if object moved from origin

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I have succesfully created a rope object using the screw and curve modifiers. But when I move the object away from the origin the path gets more distorted the further I move it away.

The only way I've been able to fix it is to apply both modifiers. This leaves me with no ability to modify the object path or rope strand dimensions easily. See below for examples. You can see the underlying sine curve

[image: Good rope]

[image: Starting to distort as it is moved away from origin]

[image: Highly distorted]

Comment: I guess what you need to do is to move both the object and the curve

Comment: Either move both objects together or parent the curve to the rope. When parenting, be aware that pressing ESC while moving will screw up the rope.

Answer (score 2):

If you move the object away from the curve, on some axis, it may mess up the array, so put the origin of the curve at its beginning point, put the object at the same position, give it the *Array* and the *Curve* modifiers, and if you want your object to be somewhere else, select BOTH the object and the curve. As Metaphor said, to make it easier you can parent the curve to the object.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to @metaphor_set for the suggestions! I found that using the parent command worked the best.